# How to manually set UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview

I created UITableVewCell subclass for my cell and I want set height of cell to 70px. It's possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution;

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Delegate method of UITableView,similarly there are lot's of method for other purpose too.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 70;
}
```

For more details follow the below link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3